# How do you deal with a non-standard date format in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date

I am getting a report with a few fields that are set at m/d/y hh:mm (so yes one digit for one digit months).  I will not be importing these in the future so I would rather not rely on changing the input file.  How can mysql adjust to that format so that I can do date lookups and time based queries?

Example:

table a -

empID

lastlogin

How do I search for employees that have logged in this month using the lastlogin field as the date field described above?

Comment: MySQL has [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for manipulating dates.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not appear to show any research effort.

Comment: @Strawberry - Sorry I didn't list out the 5-6 things I tried but didn't think they were relevant.  If someone has dealt with it before reading my drivel isn't going to help.  Also I searched the site before and didn't see this asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL function `str_to_date()` is pretty flexible.  Even though it seems like it prefers MM/DD/YYYY formats, it does work with M/D/YYYY.

So you can do:

```
select a.*
from a
where str_to_date(lastlogin, '%m/%d/%Y') >= now() - interval 30 days;
```

However, you shouldn't store dates in the database as strings.  It is a much better idea to store them as actual `date` or `datetime` fields.  You can do the transformation once, when loading the data, and then not have to worry about the data.